# Dividir columna de mysql en 3 columnas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos que maneja usuarios sobre una tabla, llamada a partir de ahora users. El software permite agregar campos al registro del usuario, pero esos campos nuevos no se añaden a la tabla users, si no que se generan en otra tabla que se llama "extra_fields". hasta ahi bien, en la tabla "extra_fields" el sistema almacena los nuevos campos generados con un id para cada uno.

Cuando uno graba un usuario nuevo la tabla "extra_fields_values" graba los datos de los "extra_fields".

Ahi mi problema, necesito sacar estos datos para poder armar un mini programa de consultas referente a los usuarios.

El problema es que la tabla "extra_fields_values" graba sobre una sola columna llamada "value" todos los campos agregados en el registro del usuario, y con una columna "id_field" conecta con la tabla "extra_fields" para saber cual es el dato que graba y con una columna "id_item" conecta con la tabla user para identeficar el usuario.

Cuando hago un inner join entre la tabla "user" y "extra_fields_values" me trae los registros bien, pero el problema que tengo que me repite el mismo usuario por cada campo grabado en la columna "value"

Lo que necesito es poder dividir (justamente en 3 porque son los camppos extras que tengo en el registro del usuario) en 3 la columna de "value" y que por el "id_field" pueda asiganar a cada columna sus valores correspondientes(por ejemplo el documento de identidad) y que a traves de un inner join con la tabla users pueda mostrar el usuario con sus 3 columnas con esos datos.

Espero haber sido claro

Muchas gracias
Saludos!

Comment: muestra la consulta que estas haciendo

Comment: el problema es que ni siquiera como armar la consulta. hasta el inner join llegue, es algo deducible, pero necesito saber como separar la columna en 3. a traves de subconsultas o como sea.

Comment: No es muy claro. Pon un ejemplo de las tablas, qué campos tiene cada una, a ver si se entiende mejor. Te enredas mucho en la explicación.